# Import a Simple Graph into Neo4j

Tags: database, graph, import, neo4j, cypher

I have a simple graph in GraphML or GEXF format and I would like to import it to Neo4j graph database to be able to query on such graph using Cypher. The graph in not that much big and I can say its in middle size so I seek a simple way to import such data to Neo4j. I know the question is simple, but I'm stuck with it!

Answer (score 4):

You can do that with the Gremlin plugin as documented at 
http://neo4j-contrib.github.io/gremlin-plugin/#rest-api-load-a-sample-graph

Comment: Yep. But I would like to query later using Cypher and not Gremlin! So maybe I need to import directly by Cypher!

Comment: Behrooz, Just because you import with Gremlin doesn't mean you're locked it. Gremlin just handles reading the GraphML file and passing the values to Neo4j, which actually creates them. After this import, you'll be able to use and query your data using anything available to `Neo4j`.